# Почему сдвигается объект ( CSS )?

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть страничка с товарами, но почему при определенной сортировке или переходе на другую стр один объект может сдвигаться, хотя, когда применить другую сортировку все объекты ровные. Фото прикреплю ниже.

Есть такая же страничка в другом интернет-магазине и там все объекты встают ровно при любой из сортировок и т.д.

Я склоняюсь к тому, что это проблема где-то в CSS коде или самых изображениях.

Вот css код товара в списке товаров:

```
.product-list .item {
    width:33%;
    padding: 10px 20px 20px 0;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Фото №1

[image: Товар сдвигается]

Фото №2

[image: Товар не сдвигается]

Что это может быть и что мне следует предпринять ?

Спасибо

Comment: Две строки в названии товара. От этого высота блока изменяется, геометрия меняется, блоки сдвигаются

Comment: Нужно увеличить вертикальное расстояние между блоками ?

Comment: И оно просто сложится с высотой и в итоге всё равно всё будет скакать. Нужно сделать так, чтобы высота у всех блоков была одинаковой независимо от числа строк в тексте. Или же перейти на более подходящие технологии вроде inline-block / flexbox / grid, а не применять флоаты не по назначению

Comment: Спасибо. Применил inline-block, а float убрал и все сработало. Буду знать